# With Java one shouldn't depend on initialization. Is this also the case with Python?

Tags: java, python, security, constructor, static

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076837/mobile-java/twelve-rules-for-developing-more-secure-java-code.html recommends to not depend on initialization. Specifically, it recommends the below. Are these recommendations also good practice in Python?

> **Don't depend on initialization**
>
> Most Java developers think there is no way to allocate an object
>   without running a constructor. But this isn't true: there are several
>   ways to allocate noninitialized objects.
>
> The easy way to protect yourself against this problem is to write your
>   classes so that before any object does anything, it verifies that it
>   has been initialized. You can do this as follows:
>
> - Make all variables private. If you want to allow outside code to    access variables in an object, this should be done via get and set
>     methods. (This keeps outside code from accessing noninitialized
>     variables.) If you're following Rule 3, you'll make the get and set
>     methods final.
> - Add a new private boolean variable, initialized, to each object.
> - Have each constructor set the initialized variable as its last action    before returning.
> - Have each nonconstructor method verify that initialized is true       before doing anything. (Note that you may have to make exceptions to
>     this rule for methods called by your constructors. If you do this,
>     it's best to make the constructors call only private methods.)If your 
>     class has a static initializer, you will need to do the same thing at 
>     the class level. Specifically, for any class that has a static
>     initializer, follow these steps:
> - Make all static variables private. If you want to allow outside code     to access static variables in the class, this should be done
>     via       static get and set methods. This keeps outside code from
>     accessing       noninitialized static variables. If you're following
>     Rule 3, you'll      make the get and set methods final.
> - Add a new private static boolean variable, classInitialized, to the      class.
> - Have the static constructor set the initialized variable as its last     action before returning.
> - Before doing anything, have each static method and each constructor      verify that classInitialized is true. (Note: constructors are
>     required to call a constructor of the superclass, or another
>     constructor of the same class, as their first action. So you will
>     have to do that before you check classInitialized.)

Comment: This falls at the first hurdle where python is concerned. There's no such thing as 'private' anything, except by convention

Comment: Short answer is yes. These rules are all lending themselves to limiting the scope of variables and methods as much as possible. This is a best practice in almost every language. I hope this answers your question

Comment: *"Most Java developers think there is no way to allocate an object without running a constructor. But this isn't true: there are several ways to allocate noninitialized objects."* And then not a single example. That should be a red flag for *anyone* reading the article.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is that quote false?

Comment: @Daniel: I think without citation or example, it's *suspect*. A class with a well-designed constructor shouldn't need anything so ridiculously clunky as an `initialized` member. Instead, it should either initialize, or throw. But I'm not going to argue in a vacuum with the authors; it's incumbent upon *them* to present, and defend, examples. Anything else is empty rhetoric.

Comment: There's `clone`, deserialization, and probably something that uses reflection, but off the top of my head, I can't see how untrusted code would be able to use those to construct an object in a half-initialized state if it had proper access limitations and the class implemented `clone` and de/serialization properly.

Comment: Python doesn't allow you to load a section of untrusted code, so the whole point about security is moot. (Though you could have the whole Python system running some mobile code). No idea if there is the equivalent of the Princeton `finalizer` technique, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @user2357112 Reflection always runs the constructor. Java Deserialisation is not implementable in the public reflection API. In cases such as the `finalizer` technique or other self-registration, at the very least a subclass constructor is invoked (technically since 1.5/1.6ish) even if construction doesn't complete normally (throws an exception, or just never bothers to exit).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is yes. These rules are all lending themselves to limiting the scope of variables and methods as much as possible in order to prevent unwanted behavior. This is a best practice in almost every language. However, JAVA and python are fairly different languages so there wont be a direct analog in Python for a lot of these JAVA suggestions. I hope this answers your question

Comment: Thanks. Could you please be more specific about which suggestions do and don't have a (direct) analog?

Comment: yes take a look at kdopen's comment. There are also differences in how each language handles typing. JAVA is statically typed and Python is dynamically types.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that the only recommendations that apply to Python are the ones involving initialized and classInitialized, except that these will be dynamically typed variables instead of statically typed booleans?

Comment: See my answer - it is impossible to have an "uninitialized variable" in Python

Answer (score 1):

Most of these points address controlling the initialization of private member and static variables. There are no private variables in Python. Certainly you can do the following which, by convention, indicates that `__private` is, well, private.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__private = None

    def getPrivate(self):
        return self.__private

    def failUninitialized(self):
        return self.this_will_fail
```

And then provide properties for setters and getters, but that "private" variable is still available as `_A__private`

```
> a = A()
> a._A__private = 1
> a.getPrivate()
1
>
```

The way that Python catches 'uninitialized' members is that don't exist if they've never been assigned to ... and you get an exception.

Python creates member variables the first time they are assigned to. There is no 'declaration' of variables without assignment. Thus they either exist, and are initialized, or they have never been initialized and thus do not exist. In the latter case, you get an `AttributeError` exception.

If `getPrivate` was somehow invoked without `__init__` ever being called (which could happen if a derived class did not invoke the base class's constructor), it would throw an exception because the member did not have an attribute called `_A__private`

More simply, the following will fail

```
> a = A()
> a.failUninitialized()
```

because the object `a` does not have an initialized member variable called `this_will_fail`

Comment: Not sure I understand the last sentence of your answer.

Comment: Added some more explanation